# Does sorting value types create copies?

Tags: c#

How is sorting for value types implemented in C#?

I cannot delete the (implicit) default constructor for structs to see that the compiler/runtime doesn't call it but I suspect it does a copy when sorting as even holding a temporary (value) to do a swap on implies a copy, though this could be achieved with pointers instead, but there is nothing I can see in the generics code to indicate it does anything special for value types vs reference types.

The IL

```
IL_0060: ldloc.0      // fooByValues
IL_0061: ldloc.1      // comparer
IL_0062: callvirt     instance void class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<valuetype DevOpsCourse.Tests.Common.FunctionalComparerTest/FooByValue>::Sort(class [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.IComparer`1<!0/*valuetype DevOpsCourse.Tests.Common.FunctionalComparerTest/FooByValue*/>)
IL_0067: nop
```

Just refers to a virtual call I cannot look into so I have no idea how it is really implemented.

I couldn't find any documentation pertaining to this either.

Comment: Structs are copied when passed as parameters, reference objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @Glubus I am aware of this

Comment: You could use a memory profiler and watch the number of objects being created.

Comment: What if you create your own struct and log something in their constructor?

Comment: @UweKeim This sounds very interesting, is there a known tool for this? If I cannot find documentation to confirm/deny my suspicion this would be the next best thing!

Comment: @Glubus I can't, the default constructor I cannot override for struct types.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Yes but swapping values and swapping references are two different things, on the stack/heap doesn't matter much. I just want to know how the implementation works, apologies if the question is vague.

Comment: @Glubus - not really. Struct variables are copied when passed as parameters. Reference variables are *also* copied when passed as parameters (you get a copy of the reference, not a copy of the object that is referenced). Pass by reference in .NET means that the called code can change the assignment of the variable that was used to pass the parameter and that's not true by default for either type (you have to use `ref` or `out` for the callee's variable to be assignable)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the question posed in the title, the answer is Yes.

---

You won't see anything special here. *variables* of value types hold the value *within* themselves. Any time you see any form of assignment to a variable of a value type, that's going to be a copy.

Variables of reference types hold *references* to the actual object that holds the data. When you perform an assignment to a variable of a reference type, you get a copy of the *reference* but the reference still refers to the same object.

That's why you won't see anything special here - it's all just assignments to variables that "do the right thing" for both value types and reference types.

(And reference types aren't passed by reference when used as parameters. Parameter passing is always pass by value by default, but what's being passed is a *variable*, not a *value*)

---

> though this could be achieved with pointers instead

Bear in mind that most structs should be small anyway. Swapping pointers to them (even if such pointers existed) could well be more work than swapping the values because the pointers could well be larger than the struct.

E.g. an array of a value type is a chunk of memory containing the actual values - not a chunk of memory containing pointers to the values. The only way to swap the position of two such values is literally to overwrite them.

Comment: I always thought that an array of a value type is a chunk of memory containing pointers. Structs which are items of an array are stored in a heap, aren't they?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - no, no pointers. Heap is usually [irrelevant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this was the most informative (and the linked article is a gem).

Answer (score 1):

The sort algorithms in the BCL do create copies. They essentially do the same thing as in:

```
struct MyStruct { ... }

MyStruct a = ...;
MyStruct b = a; //copy
```

It's a simple assignment.

Struct constructors play no role here. .NET does not have the concept of a copy constructor. Also, the default constructor is not called here. Structs are always copied by simply copying all fields (essentially `memcpy`).

Even if assignments happen through pointers this still does the same thing. In fact an array access such as `array[0] = array[1];` can done through an IL concept called a managed pointer. Using managed pointers you can obtain a pointer to a subject and directly read and write that subobject. C# now exposes this with their latest `ref` features. You can say:

```
MyStruct[] array = ...;
ref MyStruct item0 = ref array[0];
item0 = ...; //updates the array
```

This is safe, managed code.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `List<T>.Sort` delegates to `Array.Sort`, which does create a temporary copy of the array member during swap operations. For value types, this would mean that values needing moved will be copied.